# How can you make sure Callback.dispose gets called?

Tags: dart

I'm looking at the js-interop library (http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) and (http://dart-lang.github.com/js-interop/docs/js/Callback.html). I want to setup a multi-fire callback using `new Callback.many`. It says that I have to make sure to call `dispose()` otherwise I might get a memory leak. What's the best way to make sure `dispose()` gets called when my page is unloaded?

Comment: I sent email to the js-interop authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to explicitily dispose the [Callback](http://dart-lang.github.com/js-interop/docs/js/Callback.html) when your page is unload. The browser should clean up them as other javascript variables used in the page.

[dispose()](http://dart-lang.github.com/js-interop/docs/js/Callback.html#dispose) should be used when you know that a [Callback](http://dart-lang.github.com/js-interop/docs/js/Callback.html) will not be used anymore. It's like removing a reference on an unused object to allow it to be garbage collected.

Technically, all callbacks are referenced in a Map to allow communication between js and dart. So even if your code do not keep reference on the callback, it will not be garbage collected. Calling `dispose()` will remove that reference and make the callback free to be garbage collected.